# Erratic behaviour of onclick method in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `listview` and each item in the `listview` contains a `button`. 
There is the `method` which is called when the `button` is **clicked**.

The expected behaviour is that the **text** is changed to **red** and the size of the text is **increased**.

Now this works perfectly fine when the `listview` fits within the screen. However, when the `listview` doesn't fit in the screen,

if I press the `button` of the first item that doesn't fit, both that item AND the first item in the `listview` get highlighted. Similarly,

if I press the **first item** in the `listview`, both that and the first item that doesn't fit get **highlighted**.

I'm assuming I need to use the position variable somehow solve this problem however I am failing to identify what the problem is.

```
public void clicking(View v) {
    Button b = (Button) v;
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
    String buttontext = b.getText().toString();
    TextView betidtextbox = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gid);
    LinearLayout layoutt = (LinearLayout) layout.getParent();
    String betid = betidtextbox.getText().toString();
    if (b.getTag() == "highlighted") {
        b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        b.setTextSize(18);
        b.setTag("");
        selection = "home";
    else {
        b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EB102E"));
        b.setTextSize(20);
        b.setTag("highlighted");
        selection = "home";
```

Activity code:

```
public class AllGameslistActivity extends ListActivity  {
private Bet newBet = new Bet();
private double stake = 0.00;
private String name = "";
private double newwinnings;
private String newwinningstoString;
private View itemView;
private String selection;
private ArrayList<TipDisplayer> tomee = new ArrayList<>();

// Progress Dialog
private static String url_all_games = "***";

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gamesList;

// url to get all products list

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_GAMELIST = "gamelist";
private static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
private static final String TAG_LEAGUE = "League";
private static final String TAG_TEAMS = "Teams";
private static final String TAG_BET = "Bet";
private static final String TAG_ODDS = "Odds";
private static final String TAG_DATETIMER = "DateTimer";
private static final String TAG_COMMENTS = "Comments";
private static final String TAG_TYPE = "Type";


// products JSONArray
JSONArray allgames = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.all_bets);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);



    menu menu =  (menu) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
    menu.betnowclick();
    SessionManager session;
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    name = user.get(SessionManager.USERNAME);
    menu.updateinfo(getName());

    // Hashmap for ListView
    gamesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllGames().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();



}



/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 */
class LoadAllGames extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_games, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Games: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Games
                allgames = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GAMELIST);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < allgames.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = allgames.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String league = c.getString(TAG_LEAGUE);
                    String odds = c.getString(TAG_ODDS);
                    String comments = c.getString(TAG_COMMENTS);
                    String type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                    String bet = c.getString(TAG_BET);
                    String datetimer = c.getString(TAG_DATETIMER);
                    String Teams = c.getString(TAG_TEAMS);
                    Double Odds = Double.parseDouble(odds);



                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_LEAGUE,league);
                    map.put(TAG_ODDS,odds);
                    map.put(TAG_COMMENTS,comments);
                    map.put(TAG_TYPE,type);
                    map.put(TAG_BET,bet);
                    map.put(TAG_DATETIMER,datetimer);
                    map.put(TAG_TEAMS, Teams);
                    Log.d("id", id);
                    Log.d("league", league);
                    Log.d("odds", odds);
                    Log.d("comments", comments);
                    Log.d("Type", type);
                    Log.d("bet", bet);
                    Log.d("datetimer", datetimer);
                    Log.d("teams",Teams);

                    tomee.add(i, new TipDisplayer(id, league, Teams, bet, odds, datetimer, comments, type));

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    gamesList.add(map);
                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * *
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        // updating UI from Background Thread
    PopulateList();


    }


}
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TipDisplayer> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(AllGameslistActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, tomee);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        TextView leaguetxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.leaguetxt);
        TextView datetxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.datetxt);
        TextView teamstxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.teamstxt);
        TextView bettxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bettxt);
        TextView betid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gid);
        TextView typetxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.difficultytxt);
        TextView commentstxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.commenttxt);
        Button oddsbtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.oddsbutton);
        TipDisplayer currentwriter = tomee.get(position);
        String leaguetext = currentwriter.getLeague();
        String datetext = currentwriter.getDatetimer();
        String teamstext = currentwriter.getTeams();
        String bettext = currentwriter.getBet();
        String typetext = currentwriter.getType();
        String idtext = currentwriter.getId();
        String commentsText = currentwriter.getComments();
        String oddstext = currentwriter.getOdds();
        leaguetxt.setText(leaguetext);
        datetxt.setText(datetext.substring(0,datetext.lastIndexOf(":")) + " GMT");
        teamstxt.setText(teamstext);
        bettxt.setText(bettext);
        betid.setText(idtext);
        commentstxt.setText(commentsText);
        oddsbtn.setText(oddstext);
        typetxt.setText(typetext);
        if (typetext.equals("Low Risk")) {
            typetxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#067103"));
        }
        else if (typetext.equals("Medium Risk")) {
            typetxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D9D216"));
        }
        else if (typetext.equals("Longshot")) {
            typetxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F75528"));
        }


        return itemView;


    }
}

private void PopulateList() {
    ArrayAdapter<TipDisplayer> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
public void SelectBet(View v) {
    clicking(v);
}



public void clicking(View v) {
    Button b = (Button) v;
    ListView lv = getListView();
    int position = lv.getPositionForView(v);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
    String buttontext = b.getText().toString();
    TextView betidtextbox = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gid);
    LinearLayout layoutt = (LinearLayout) layout.getParent();
    String betid = betidtextbox.getText().toString();
    if (b.getTag().toString().equals("highlighted")) {
        b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        b.setTextSize(18);
        b.setTag("");
        selection = "home";

        TextView teamss = (TextView) layoutt.findViewById(R.id.teamstxt);
        String teams = teamss.getText().toString();
        newBet.generateoddstesting(betid, buttontext, false,teams,selection);
        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
        EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        if (mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
            stake = 0.00;
            newwinnings = 0.00;
            potentialWinnings.setText("0.00");

        } else {
            mEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                              int count, int after) {
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int before, int count) {
                    if (s.length() != 0) {
                        stake = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                        newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f",newodds) + "/1");
                        potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                        newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();

                    } else {
                        stake = 0.00;
                        newwinnings = 0.00;
                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f",newodds) + "/1");
                        potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                        newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();

                    }
                }
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });
            //stake = Double.parseDouble(mEdit.getText().toString());
            newwinnings = stake*newodds;
            potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
            newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();


        }
    } else {
        b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EB102E"));
        b.setTextSize(20);
        b.setTag("highlighted");
        selection = "home";
        String getodds = b.getText().toString();
        EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        if (mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
            stake = 0.00;
            newwinnings = 0.00;
            TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
            potentialWinnings.setText("0.00");
        } else {
            mEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                              int count, int after) {
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int before, int count) {
                    if (s.length() != 0) {
                        stake = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                        newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f",newodds) + "/1");
                        potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                        newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();
                    } else {
                        stake = 0.00;
                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                        newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f",newodds) + "/1");
                        potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                        newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();
                    }
                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });
            stake = Double.parseDouble(mEdit.getText().toString());
            TextView teamms = (TextView) layoutt.findViewById(R.id.teamstxt);
            String teams = teamms.getText().toString();
            newBet.generateoddstesting(betid, buttontext, true,teams,selection);
            double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
            newwinnings = stake * newodds;
            TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
            TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
            myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f",newodds) + "/1");
            potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
            newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();


        }
    }

}
```

list_item layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/whatisthis"
android:weightSum="160">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/leaguetxt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="English Premier League"
        android:textColor="#067103"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/datetxt"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="BET UNTIL : 23/05/2015 15:00 GMT"
        android:textColor="#067103"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="30">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teamstxt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text="Sevilla FC - FC Barcelona"
        android:textColor="#067103"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/bettxt"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:text="FC Barcelona Win and BTTS"
        android:textColor="#067103"
        android:textStyle="bold" />





</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="0dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/difficultytxt"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#067103"
        android:text="MEDIUM RISK"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/commenttxt"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#067103"
        android:text = "  "/>
</ScrollView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/oddsbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:tag = ""
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="SelectBet"
        android:text="3.60"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id = "@+id/gid"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

XML Code of Activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/timeleft"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:text="Stake"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:hint="0"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="65"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="@string/potentialwinnings"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bettingodds"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="\@1.00/1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textStyle="italic">


        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/potentialwinnings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="0.00"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:onClick="NewBetMaker"
        android:text="Save Bet!"></Button>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.example.albert.betterapp.menu"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_menu" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
         />


</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

So each item in the listview has a button, when I click on the button for the first item in the listview, the onclick method is run for both the first item and the first not visible item, if I do it for the second item, its run for the second item and the second not visible item. Similarly if I scroll down and click the first not visible item, its run for that item and the first item and the pattern continues.

Comment: it the tag is a String, you should use equals to compare it. `if ("highlighted".equals( (String) b.getTag()))`

Comment: Yeah fixed, that's not the issue tho as it's running the onclick method for a button I did not click in a different position in the listview, so the problem has to be somewhere with the positioning

Comment: Are you using a custom listadapter to manage the listview?

Comment: can you post the relative xml code of the button?

Comment: There is no way that I can see a problem with this small amount of code. I think you should post the code that calls clicking(), perhaps the Listview code or/and the Adapter (since you mention positioning).

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid I posted the code of the whole activity, the xml of the single item and the xml of the activity with the listview. You can find all the info you asked for there

Comment: I am not an Android expert, but what i see is that you only have the onclick function assigned to one button. From what i got from your post, i assumed you have more buttons. If you only have one button then only this button will invoke the onclick function

Comment: It's a listview which gets dynamically populated so the amount of buttons is relative, this is just the layout of every single item; think of it as a table, this is the layout of each row in the table, how many rows are there varies.

Comment: Which xml is list_item layout?  Please just add the xml filenames to avoid confusion.

Comment: Why re-edit to add back the bold and highlighting? It just makes it harder to read. Highlight things which need to stand out. "Clicked" "text" "increased" etc are not really things which require highlighting in bold (imo). Or at least be consistent, you've highlighted the word "text" once out of two in the same sentence.

Comment: I didn't do this edit, somebody else did.

Comment: Now if you are to comment, I suggest on focusing on the problem at hand, not on the style of somebodies formatting.]

Answer (score 0):

inside your `getView()` you could use `OnClickListener`:

```
oddsbtn.setText(oddstext);
oddsbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Do whatever you want, view v is your button.
});
```

Comment: yeah i'm aware, produces same outcome tho

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you just added `getPositionForView`() call from the ListView. This is not a reliable way to do it. The reason is the position in the AdapterView is not well defined. It is not directly related to which row is being selected. The documentation does not even say it is.

However you should be able to achieve your goal by adding code onto the Adapter. I don't have much time right now. For now, please read up a good webpage tutorial @ [Android Listview](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html).
Please look at code snippet from the page:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
```

**EDIT 1:**
One suspect code is that you need to pass the ArrayList to the Adapter. You should not depend on the static object `tomee`. Adapters prefer objects that are stable and "final".

**Change FROM:**

```
private void PopulateList() {
    ArrayAdapter<TipDisplayer> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
```

**TO**:

```
private void PopulateList() {
    ArrayAdapter<TipDisplayer> adapter = new MyListAdapter(tomee);
```

**Add**:

```
public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<TipDisplayer> tomee) {
    super(AllGameslistActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, tomee);
    this.tomee = tomee;  // declare tomee in the Adapter, don't use static

}
```

Note:

- In the Adapter, add another constructor to accept the ArrayList, supporting the change in `PopulateList`().
- The other suspect code (in my opinion) is calling `PopulateList`() in `onPostExecute`(). This is a clever idea, I think, but I am not sure of its reliability, need further thought. Fix the one above first.

Comment: I added it there but didn't use it anywhere in the code. I noticed that if I add another item, the second item gets highlighted when i highlight that one. I think it has something to do with the visibility of the listview. Since on average 4 items fit on the screen, when i scroll down to the 5th one it is treated as if it was the 1st one and the 6th one is treated like the 2nd one, idk if that was well explained but that's what I've noticed

Comment: @mankee, I hope that the suggested code under EDIT 1 resolves the issue of scrolling down and getting items repeated always. I don't understand your statement "has something to do with the visibility of the listview". The listview generally would not show all the items, so that's normal, nothing to do with visibility.

Comment: I made the changes but it didn't help. I use the same logic and similar adapters in my other methods which work without issue. I think the problem has to be within the onclick method which is run. I updated the question with a picture and description to try to better explain the issue. Hope it helps.